# Flutter Hot Reload not working in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

new to flutter. created a new project using Intellij flutter plugin. Ran the app on an ios simulator using the play icon on the intellij, which runs the app in an IphoneX simulator. Made some cosmetic changes to the main.dart file but i) the hot reload, lightning, button is disabled ii) also code gets auto saved in intellij, so not sure what i need to do to test hot reload.

as a matter of fact, i have to delete the app from my iPhoneX simulator and rerun from IntelliJ to pick up the changes.

Comment: After 3 hours : and all of sudden the ide poped up a message that it supports hot reload and it started working !!

Comment: I have the same error, last update killed the hot reload on save, i have to hit the reload button now :-( did anyone know, how to set it in intellij to reload on save?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is facing the same problem, I solved it using the answer of XQDD in: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19151

which consists in updating adb version:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Answer (score 2):

Try to invalidate cache and restart Android Studio, as well as run the command to clean the flutter build.

Concrete instructions
In Android Studio, go to `File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart --> Invalidate and Restart`

After restart, run the command in the terminal: `flutter clean`

After that, your reload should be working again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the usual workarounds. Clear cache, `flutter clean`, ect, however, none worked for me.

**The only thing worked for me was to close the IntelliJ and delete `.idea` and `build` directories.**
After opening the project it was working as expected.

Also make sure that hot reloading is enabled in the flutter settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".